# Where are my Fallout Shelter Screenshots saved?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I took a screenshot, however I don't want to link FO Shelter to my social media... where are they screenshots saved for Android (bonus points if you want to answer for iOS too!)

Answer (score 1):

In android, your screenshots are saved in `/storage/sdcard0/android/data/com.bethsoft.falloutshelter/files`
Another easy way to access screenshots in the future is getting [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and when you take an ingame screenshot, press share and share the screenshot to ES Save to... and you will be able to save it to any directory you want.

Comment: iOS screenshot are saved in the camera roll